# android-get data from a site

Tags: android

How can I get data from a site to a variable x?
I want that everytime I use this x, x will get his data from this site.
for example how can I get this data 3.856 from the site http://www.dollargate.net/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/first, download the site:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request= new HttpGet(url);      
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

then look for the following text in content:

```
<div id="tabcontent1">
    <div id="dollar_1">שער הדולר היציג הוא:</div>
    <div id="dollar_2">
```

the number will be right after this text

PS: don't forget to add permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an http request and parse the response, the parsing of course depends on every website.
An example on how to make an http request, if you don't know that already you can find in the android samples (you should have this in the Android SDK folder), for instance here: android-sdk/samples/android-16/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/client/NetworkUtilities.java

Good Luck!